# How to delete migration files in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-io

I would like to remove/delete a migration file. How would I go about doing that? I know there are similar questions on here but as an update, is there a better way than doing script/destroy?

Also, should I do a `db:reset` or `db:drop` if I remove/delete a migration?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

I usually:

1. Perform a `rake db:migrate VERSION=XXX` on all environments, to the version before the one I want to delete.
2. Delete the migration file manually.
3. If there are pending migrations (i.e., the migration I removed was not the last one), I just perform a new `rake db:migrate` again.

If your application is already on production or staging, it's safer to just write another migration that destroys your table or columns.

Another great reference for migrations is: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Comment: Would deleting the migration and then running a db:migrate wipe out the table that was created?

Comment: No, since Rails would not know how to delete it. It needs to call the `self.down` method defined on your migration to "downgrade" your database.

Comment: I just edited my response with 2 good references, check that out.

Comment: Oh, I see. Ok, thanks, this is exactly what I was wondering about. Thanks Again!

Comment: If you've already deleted the file, without realizing rails will not let go that easily, `rake db:migrate:status` will show you the ID of the missing file, which you can use to recreate it. Once it's back, you can follow this answer's advice to victory.

Comment: It seems that for everyone 1. step is clear, but for me it's not:( What does it mean "...on all environments, to the version before the one I want to delete."? Thanks!

Comment: @Lucas, once the migration file is removed, it cannot be reversed anymore. That's why you must revert it on all environments it already ran (production, development, testing, staging, etc) before deleting its file. That's also why I wrote that it's safer to just create another migration to revert that old one, once it's already ran on production.

Answer (score 84):

Another way to delete the migration:

```
$ rails d migration SameMigrationNameAsUsedToGenerate
```

Use it before `rake db:migrate` is executed because changes in database will stay forever :) - or remove changes in Database manually

Comment: "If your application is already on production or staging, it's safer to just write another migration that destroys your table or columns." So changes do not stay in database forever

Comment: By the way, "d" stands for "destroy".

Answer (score 26):

Run below commands from app's home directory:

1. `rake db:migrate:down VERSION="20140311142212"` (here version is the timestamp prepended by rails when migration was created. This action will revert DB changes due to this migration)
2. `Run "rails destroy migration migration_name"` (migration_name is the one use chose while creating migration. Remove "**timestamp_**" from your migration file name to get it)

Comment: rake destroy migration AddFileToTable
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'destroy'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: For #2 the correct command is:
`rails d migration migration_name`

Comment: Thanks for the "remove timestamp_" hint that's what I needed

Answer (score 10):

We can use,

```
$ rails d migration table_name
```

Which will delete the migration.

Comment: I think it should be model name rather than table_name

Answer (score 10):

You can also run a down migration like so:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=versionnumber
```

Refer to the [Ruby on Rails guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#running-specific-migrations) on migrations for more info.

Comment: If you specify a versionnumber, does it decide whether to go up or down accordingly?

Answer (score 10):

None of these answers quite fit the problem i had as the migration i wanted to delete was missing:
I had created and run a migration in some other branch, which was then discarded. The problem is when a migration is run, rails adds the version into a `schema_migrations` table in the database. So even if it isn't listed in your db structure or schema, rails looks for it. 
You can reveal these orphaned migrations by running:

`rails db:migrate:status`

Note the versions of the missing migrations and head into the db console:

`rails dbconsole`

Now remove the versions from the migration table manually:

`delete from schema_migrations where version='<version>';`

You should now be good.

Comment: This is correct. Keep in mind you must also revert any changes to the db from the original branch before switching to your new branch. Deleting the record of the schema migration will not also delete these orphaned tables.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes I found myself deleting the migration file and then deleting the corresponding entry on the table schema_migrations from the database. Not pretty but it works.

Answer (score 3):

This also works in Rails 5.

If the migration was the most recent one you can remove the database column(s) that the migration added by doing:

```
rake db:rollback
```

then remove the migration file itself by running:

```
rails d migration WhateverYourMigrationWasNamed.rb
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at 4.1 Rolling Back

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

$ rake db:rollback

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem:

1. **rails d migration fuu**
    -this deleted the migration with the last timestamp
2. **rails d migration fuu**
    -this deleted the other migration
3. use git status to check that is not on the untracked files anymore
4. **rails g migration fuu**

That fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

Side Note: 
Starting at rails 5.0.0 
`rake` has been changed to `rails`
So perform the following

rails db:migrate VERSION=0