# Deleted migration.rb file? Potential bug in rails?

Tags: migration, destroy

I am not sure if this is a bug or if this actually removed a migration.rb file.  I used generate to create the following migration:

`$ rails generate migration add_delta_to_submissions`

```
    invoke  active_record  
    create    db/migrate/20111020175649_add_delta_to_submissions.rb
```

I then realized that I neglected to include any columns, so I used the UP ARROW in the console and overwrote generate with destroy:

`$ rails destroy migration add_delta_to_submissions`

```
    invoke  active_record  
    remove    db/migrate/20111020175649_add_delta_to_submissions.rb
```

All good so far, now its time to run the migration with the column I need.  Here is where the problem comes in - I used the UP ARROW again - but only once - and added my column info:

`$ rails destroy migration add_delta_to_submissions delta:integer`

```
    invoke  active_record  
    remove    migration.rb
```

I realize I should probably NOT be using the UP ARROW for commands as volatile as GENERATE and DESTROY (lesson learned!), but that command came back stating it REMOVED the migration.rb file.  I didn't even know there was a migration.rb file - especially not one that could be removed so easily.

For kicks, I decided to try and trick the command console by adding the letter x to the end of word migration - and received this message:

`$ rails destroy migrationx add_delta_to_submissions delta:integer`

```
    Could not find generator migrationx.
```

So, I think there could be a bug with the rails destroy command.  Once it realized there was no longer a add_delta_to_submissions.rb file, it just lopped that off and tacked on the .rb to the word migration (or any word after DESTROY).  That seems a bit dangerous....

Regardless of that - I am curious to know if I have somehow compromised my RAILS environment (rails 3.1, ruby 1.8.7) now that the migration.rb file has been removed.  If so - what are my options for fixing that situation?

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: The same thing just happened to me. Did you figure out what happened?

Comment: Same thing happened to me when I ran the destroy command but attached .rb to the end of the migration name (because I'm senile).  I think it is harmless but is a bug of some kind in the generator nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

It also happens when you type a **non-existing migration name** as parameter to destroy command

```
$rails migration destroy non-existing-migration-name 

invoke    active_record
remove    migration.rb
```

But I think it is harmless.

Comment: It also happens to me.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have git on your system? The same thing happened to be today and I ran:

```
git diff | grep migration
```

Nothing came out on my system. I searched for the file and still couldn't find any migration.rb on any of my Rails 3.1 projects. Probably can ignore it without any harm?

Comment: I mean other Rails projects and files. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me.

Looks like there is a [migration.rb](http://api.rubyonrails.org/files/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration_rb.html) file within ActiveRecord, and though you can [extend ActiveRecord::Base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328984/rails-extending-activerecordbase), I'm not sure you can actually access those files from somewhere within your rails project directory.

Looks like there is some precedent for [deleting the migration file manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872586/how-to-delete-migration-files-in-rails-3) instead of through an automatic rails destroy command.