# rake db:rollback not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing my first Rails app.  I've run a few `rails generate model ...` and `rake db:migrate` commands, but I now want to change my data model and so need to undo a few migrations.

The [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#rolling-back) say I can undo a migration with `rake db:rollback`, but this isn't working.  When I run this in the console the computer thinks for a few seconds but doesn't make any changes to `db/migrate/` or `db/migrate/schema.rb`.  No output is printed to the console.

Is this behavior correct?  Shouldn't `db:rollback` be changing my schema?  If so, can anyone think why it might not be working?

I'm on Rails v. 3.2.6.

EDIT

At the moment `rake db:migrate:status` gives

```
database: db/development.sqlite3

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20120617191211  Create irs
   up     20120701154357  Create paths
   up     20120701154421  Create nodes
   up     20120702151447  ********** NO FILE **********
  down    20120702155140  Create venues
  down    20120703233833  Remove path from venues
```

Comment: Perhaps give us the output of `rake db:migrate:status`.

Comment: ok, done.  NO FILE looks kinda ominous... is that part of the problem?

Comment: Yes. `db:rollback` runs the down method in the latest applied migration, which in this case seems to be one where the file is missing.

Comment: So... am I understanding correctly that the rollback is failing because rake can't find a particular migration file whose name begins with `20120702151447`? And that the solution to my problem is to find this file and drop it into `/db/migrate/`?

Comment: Why `rake db:rollback` output an error in this case? Very frustrating!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Solution (see my comment): run

```
rake db:migrate:status
```

and correct problems you find there. In this case (per @MarkThomas' followup), you might want to check all files you need are in place.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Strangely, though, I was never able to find a file with the migration ID that rails was looking for (20120702151447).  In the end I created a "dummy" file with name `20120702151447_create_nothing.rb`, and body `class CreateNothing < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change

  end
end`.  It's not an elegant solution, but it got the job done.

Comment: I had some missing migration files due to removing a gem manually. Rather than creating the dummy file, I deleted the records from the `schema_migrations` table, like: `delete from schema_migrations where version in ('20150424220749', '20150424220748');` That fixed it for me.

Comment: @Derek that should be an answer

Comment: Just a note that you may encounter this state if you've migrated your database on a git branch other than your current working branch.

Answer (score 13):

This is what worked for me. Combine the steps given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872586/how-to-delete-migration-files-in-rails-3) and comment by dB.

1. run `rake db:migrate:status`
2. If you have a `****NO FILE****` entry, just note the version number as noFileVersion. Note the version of the entry just above no file entry(stable_version).
3. created a "dummy" file with name `noFileVersion_create_nothing.rb`, and body

```rb
class CreateNothing < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0] 
  def change 
  end 
end
```

4. run `rake db:migrate VERSION=stable_version`
5. remove the `noFileVersion_create_nothing.rb` manually.
6. run `rake db:migrate`.
7. run `rake db:migrate:status` again to check if No file entry has disappeared.

Comment: After getting this error.
Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. Please specify the Rails release the migration was written for

I added this to the dummy file:

`class CreateNothing < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
  end
end`

Answer (score 6):

The following worked for me:
`rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20190304092208`

Version number can be obtained by the following command:
`rake db:migrate:status`

This was the last version number to rollback one last migration

Comment: Very useful.  It allows one to work only on a particular migration!

Answer (score 1):

> **NOTE:** Use the suggestions with caution, it is very dangerous for non-dev environments.

---

If

```
rake db:migrate:status
```

gives you a migration that says

`up  20120702151447  ********** NO FILE **********`

Then the best thing to do would be to do a (note that the following command will drop the database):

```
rake db:reset
```

to redo all migrations. If the last migration is the one missing, then `schema.rb` will have the last migration that `rake db:migrate` will look for:

`ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20120702151447) do`

Change that number to the last one in your migrate folder.

Comment: If you have users & authentication, then make sure you take provisions not to lock yourself out.  For instance, add your user in db/seed.rb.

Comment: Fwiw, when I had this issue it was because I had run a migration and then, needing to insert a quick bug fix before continuing work on the migration-related feature, `git stash`-ed my local changes without first doing a rollback. With that in mind, the best approach might be to first unstash, rollback, and then stash again.

Comment: !! Remember that rake db:reset will drop your current database and you will lose all your data.  Be sure that's what you want to do.

Comment: The answer is very dangerous

Comment: According to this, you'd have to run `rake db:migrate:reset`, to actually run all the migrations and not just load the schema again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301794/difference-between-rake-dbmigrate-dbreset-and-dbschemaload