# how can i rollback on ruby on rails in my situation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to rollback migration on my ruby on rails project

I accidently deleted my migration file, [ID:20180214033313].

my migration status

[migration output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8f6n.png)

I tried doing `bundle exec rake:db rollback` but it didn't help and I also tried `bundle exec rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20180214033313` but it gave me the error below,

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownMigrationVersionError: 
No migration with version number 20180214033313>
```

Any suggestions on how can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean "how can I do this?" You want to roll back to a migration that you deleted. How is rake supposed to find the file you specified when you explicitly nuked it? Are you actually trying to roll back to the version *before* your deleted migration?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rake db:rollback not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320756/rake-dbrollback-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better Solutions for your situation.Assuming you have `git` initialised with your application,

**If you deleted your migration in current commit**

Execute `git stash` so that you can terminate/delete the changes you made. Now You can rollback the migrations.

**If you deleted your migration in previous commit**

You can drop your database by using the command `DROP DATABASE databasename` and you can make fresh migration.

Answer (score 2):

Aaah, today I was confronted with this same problem following the deletion of a migration. which is probably your case...

To reinstall existing migrations, do a migration reset:

```
rails db:migrate:reset
```

And to have a good knowledge about migrations, my little 12 points guide:

- **db:migrate** runs (single) migrations that have not run yet.
- **db:create** creates the database
- **db:drop** deletes the database
- **db:schema:load** creates tables and columns within the existing database following schema.rb. This will delete existing data.
- **db:setup** does db:create, db:schema:load, db:seed
- **db:reset** does db:drop, db:setup
- **db:migrate:reset** does db:drop, db:create, db:migrate
- **db:migrate:redo** runs (db:migrate:down db:migrate:up) or (db:rollback db:migrate) depending on the specified migration
- **db:schema:dump** dumps the current env's schema (and seems to create the db as well)
- **db:forward** advances the current schema version to the next one
- **db:seed** (only) runs the db/seed.rb file
- **db:migrate:down** rolls back one specific migration

Comment: Note for others:
rails db:migrate:reset
will also drop your db! Proceed with CAUTION!

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are using git then,
   You can use **git** to recover that file,
   In git status (or git gui) where you will find the list of changed files,
   There you will see

   deleted:    db/seeds.rb

   something like this for deleted files.
   Just use,

   git checkout filename

   And it will restore file.
2. If you are not using git then,
   use 
   `rake db:migrate:status` 
   and check the timestamp and create a file with exact same timestamp of deleted file and the name which you had given earlier. And add the same code like before. And do migrate.

Hope this will help

Comment: I like the idea with naming the file with the missing timestamp. This can be used when we want to keep the database with all the data, but still fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the github app for desktop, you can simply right click and discard the changes you've made.

I've done the same thing before it's a real simple rollback

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `rails db:reset`, if you deleted accidentally your files with `rails delete model MyModel`.