# drop_table migration fails to remove table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, schema.rb

I read a lot about it but i still can't get rid of one table that I have in my db:

```
create_table "votes", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "votable_id"
  t.string   "votable_type"
  t.integer  "voter_id"
  t.string   "voter_type"
  t.boolean  "vote_flag"
  t.string   "vote_scope"
  t.integer  "vote_weight"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "votes", ["votable_id", "votable_type", "vote_scope"],
          name: "index_votes_on_votable_id_and_votable_type_and_vote_scope"  
add_index "votes", ["voter_id", "voter_type", "vote_scope"],
          name: "index_votes_on_voter_id_and_voter_type_and_vote_scope"
```

I don't have a migration that create this table. But I think this table comes from a previous installation of the [acts_as_votable gem](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable). But I might have deleted this migration manually...

I tried to drop_table as follows, but it's not working. Even if I have this migration file, the votes table is still there:

```
class DropVotesTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    drop_table :votes
  end

  def down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

What should I do to delete this table from my **schema.rb** file?

***EDIT: solution***

Even after running the migration the table was still in my **schema.rb** so I used the rails console:

```
rails c
ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:votes)
rake db:migrate
```

And this table finally disappeared.

Comment: Do you have a migration which creates this table? Or these lines appear after you run `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872586/how-to-delete-migration-files-in-rails-3

Comment: I edited the code with more information about my migrations files

Comment: Have you run the migration? If so, what is the output that it produces? If it produces no output, then confirm that the VERSION (date/time stamp) of this migration file is not already contained in the `schema_migrations` table in your database -- if it is then attempting to migrate will not do anything.

Comment: I fixed it using the rails console - I edited my question! Thanks @pdobb